# storing multiple inputs in mysql and showing them in a table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to store shipping details and cart info in a table `orders`. In my cart there would have more than one product. Now I created a hidden input field as `<input type="hidden" name="product_code[]" value="{{ $product->id }}">`.

I received them in my controller as `$input = serialize(Input::get('product_code'));` , May be I can store them in this way.

But the problem is how can I show them ? Also please suggest me what would be the best way to this kinds of task.

Thank you very much.

Comment: here is an example. $user = User::all(); $user->toArray(); . it will return you an array. you can use foreach to display it.

Comment: Thank you ! Actually I had to unserialize the array data what I had received from the database. And it worked. Anyway , Thank you for your valuable comment.